# NetBeans code template for calling a function with "null" default arguments

Tags: php, templates, netbeans

My code template is the following:

```
test( $a = ${null}, $b = ${null} );
```

When I call it, the first selection, `$a` will be equal to `null`.
After editing this value, the second variable, `$b` is also changing to the same value at the same time.

It is possible make it independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also type default="default value" after your variable name, like this:

```
test( $a = ${firstarg default="null"}, $b = ${secondarg default="null"} );
```

This solution worked for me, and I found it browsing the predefined code templates. They are very helpful, and self explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

The value in braces is the "name" of the variable. With both set to `null` you're telling the template that they are the same variable. Change the names to `arga` and `argb` and you should be golden.

Where you would use the same name is for constructs like:

```
foreach (${array} as $$${value})
    echo $$${value}
```